# Why does BIOS runs really slow sometimes?

Tags: bios, ubuntu-12.04, kubuntu, dell-vostro

Sometimes, the BIOS runs really slow on my [Dell Vostro 1550](http://www.dell.com/in/business/p/vostro-1550/pd) computer (10 seconds). When I go to the BIOS setup and switch to a different tab, the new tab shows up slowly. My OS (Kubuntu) runs normally (only the BIOS runs really slow).

The Dell technician says to upgrade the BIOS. I don't think it will fix the problem.

I have been playing games, and the temperature is 80-84 ℃ when the games is running. After about an hour of gaming, Linux automatically shutdown due to too high temperature I think.

- Is that temperature too high? I Googled it and I found [this](http://www.techsupportforum.com/forums/f15/bios-runs-slow-loads-fine-626719.html#post3602680). Is it correct?
- Do you think the problem could be because of the CD drive, peripheral devices, etc.?
- Any ideas why it could be happening and how to fix it?

EDIT: problem solved now, technician replaced the fan, mobo and thermal paste. Thanks for your time.

Comment: Your computer is overheating and trying to compensate for the fact by slowing its frequency down. The solution is to replace the thermal paste being used. **You should also update your BIOS if Dell suggest that as a possible fix.** You could also of course just send it to Dell.

Comment: bios running really slow, you mean POST takes 10 sec. that's quick, aint it?

Comment: @Ramhound then how come only the BIOS runs slowly? (the OS runs at normal speed)

Comment: @NickKavadias usually it takes around 2-3 seconds

Comment: @JeffАtwoоd - Because the CPU runs 100% while in BIOS and thus heats up.  If the idle temperature is 85 then thats way to high.  Thats the type of temperature that burns up a CPU.  **A 2-3 second post isn't slow.**

Comment: @Ramhound my current idle temperature is 58 C

Comment: @Ramhound I made a mistake; when playing games the temperature is 80-84 C (it is fixed now)

Comment: @Ramhound I am going to upgrade the BIOS ofc.

Comment: @JeffАtwoоd - That is still high and at the point where the CPU will automatically shutdown in most cases.

Comment: The CPU doesn't shut down; Linux seems to shutdown automatically